# how to read the number of entities

Tags: javascript, azure

I have

```
for (var index in entries)
```

entries is the response I get from azure -query.
This entries is a object.

when I exit I want to know the number of entries.
That is 
I have to do a logic as :

```
int i;
    for (var index in entities) 
     if the for llop is exiting and this is the final iteration do som ething
```

how can I do that ? I know no idea how many entities are there

Comment: Is `entries` an array? Or array-like?

Comment: Can you share the object returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you mean the number or properties defined on `entries`, you can use this:

```
Object.keys( entries ).length
```

Btw, you don't need a for-in loop. You can iterate like so:

```
Object.keys( entries ).forEach(function ( key ) {
    var value = entries[ key ];
    // do things with value
});
```